# Is there a possibility to find out the technology used for creating a mobile application?

Tags: android, ios, security, mobile

I have discovered it is possible to find out how a website is built by using services like Wappalyzer, SimilarTech or BuiltWith (they check HTTP headers, ping responses, cookies, comments and other fancy things). Now I am wondering: can you find how a mobile application (Android, iOS) is built by using similar techniques / services? I know that the code is compiled and one should not try to reverse engineer it (for obvious copyright reasons)... but can it be done without "breaking the rules" (I mean by at least discovering how a service works, not the code / algorithm behind it?)

Disclaimer: This is only for educational and security reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer: As you mention, reverse engineering is usually not permitted by EULAs and may be illegal in some countries. Make sure that you know what rules apply before venturing into this area.**

For iOS you can reverse engineer binaries using thing like [iOS Reverse Engineering Toolkit](https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/introducing-the-ios-reverse-engineering-toolkit) and [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/faq.html). This does of course not produce the same level of code as the actual source code but it can provide some insight into how applications are made.

If you're interested in finding how communication works, there are a few ways to monitor network traffic from an iPhone using a computer. This is done using RVI which is a bit of a hassle. Apple has a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1176/_index.html) on it (Search for RVI on the page) and I found [this blog](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/02/07/remote-packet-capture-for-ios-devices.html) providing some detail. I've only used it once and I remember it being a pain to set up in Wireshark with no good details provided on how to configure it, you'll have to tinker a bit with the settings to get it right.

When it comes to Java there's a tonne of resources out there on reverse-engineering and it's generally a lot easier than compiled code, however obfuscation does of course make it harder. [JAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler)) is one of the more popular decompilers.

Answer (score 1):

On android you can obfuscate your code with http://proguard.sourceforge.net

I would assume most apps on the play store are obfuscated. I am not sure about IOS.

You can always run the GNU "strings" command to extract plaintext from a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

For Android:

- First you need to find APK file. There are dozens of mirrors, where .apk (or .apks) files can be downloaded.
- APK file is an archive. Unpack it or open with WinZIP / WinRAR.
- Look for files that are giveaways of language / IDE used - eg. Kotlin, Xamarin etc.